# which frame to use? angular, or Dash by Plotly?

Tags: python, angular

I want to build a website updating share price regularly, and once click on certain symbol name, the history chart will show up.

I have a python based flask server, which provide API, so basically, the website should be able to quote data API regularly ( 10 sec at least ), and draw historical chart.

I am currently hesitating between python dash and angular. To be honest, I am more familiar with python, pandas stuff. Any advice?

Comment: What's your favorite colour?

Comment: ...which is to say -- tool selection isn't really inside our scope. Indeed, it's *quite explicitly* outside our scope; library recommendation requests are entry #4 in the "some questions are still off-topic" list at https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, in addition to trending towards being opinion-based and/or places where answers can't be determined to be objectively right or wrong (as discussed at https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With dash you don't even need an API, you can work directly from the back end as it works on top of Flask by default, check this [link](https://dash.plot.ly/deployment) on how to integrate Dash charts with Flask apps.

Dash also supports [live-updating](https://dash.plot.ly/live-updates), so if you feel more comfortable with the python stack you should go with Dash.